# Assign Subshell background process pid to variable

Tags: bash, shell, variable, subshell

I am currently starting a background process within a subshell and was wondering how can I assign its pid number to a variable outside the subshell scope?
I have tried many different ways but `MYPID` always stays set to `0`.

```
MYPID = 0;
({ sleep 2 & }; $MYPID=$!)
({ sleep 2 & }; echo $!) > $MYPID
```

The only way it returns a value is with:

```
$MYPID=$({ sleep 2 & }; echo $!)
```

However this discards the background process instruction and it will only return a result after 2 seconds.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not simply `sleep 2 & mypid=$!`?

Comment: I am trying to suppress the process creation stdout. Both start showing the PID address and final with Done confirmation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`bash` shouldn't print the job status when non-interactive.

If that's indeed for an interactive `bash`, you can do:

```
{ pid=$(sleep 20 >&3 3>&- & echo "$!"); } 3>&1
```

We want `sleep`'s stdout to go to where it was before, not the pipe that feeds the `$pid` variable. So we save the *outer* stdout in the file descriptor 3 (`3>&1`) and restore it for `sleep` inside the command substitution. So `pid=$(...)` returns as soon as `echo` terminates because there's nothing left with an open file descriptor to the pipe that feeds `$pid`.

However note that because it's started from a subshell (here in a command substitution), that `sleep` will not run in a separate process group. So it's not the same as running `sleep 20 &` with regards to I/O to the terminal for instance.

Maybe better would be to use a shell that supports spawning *disowned* background jobs like `zsh` where you can do:

```
sleep 20 &! pid=$!
```

With `bash`, you can approximate it with:

```
{ sleep 20 2>&3 3>&- & } 3>&2 2> /dev/null; pid=$!; disown "$pid"
```

`bash` outputs the `[1] 21578` to stderr. So again, we save stderr before redirecting to /dev/null, and restore it for the `sleep` command. That way, the `[1] 21578` goes to `/dev/null` but `sleep`'s stderr goes as usual.

If you're going to redirect everything to /dev/null anyway, you can simply do:

```
{ apt-get update & } > /dev/null 2>&1; pid=$!; disown "$pid"
```

To redirect only stdout:

```
{ apt-get-update 2>&3 3>&- & } 3>&2 > /dev/null 2>&1; pid=$!; disown "$pid"
```

Comment: That looks great Stéphane. Thanks for that. I really liked the way you delegate outputs there. Would you mind explaining in the answer what each part is doing please? As I am learning this would be a valuable asset :) Thanks again

Comment: Sounds great, is it possible however to omit the output (except errors for the command in question) supposing I use `apt-get update` instead `sleep` I usually would send that to `> /dev/null` however since it is sending `’2>&3` the output still showing?

Comment: That’s marvellous Stéphane. thanks so much for the thorough explanation. The only thing is that on the last example with the `apt-get update` unfortunately when there is an error it won’t be logged since it is simple discarding everything. I was wondering about a way to keep the errors and discard the rest, however, I am not sure if that is possible. But I just noted that the process output [1] 23929 is sent to stderr so I believe this is a tricky thing :) Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanations and in particular for the emulation of spawning disowned background jobs.

Comment: For those of you wondering: `3>&-` closes fd 3 in the end (the innermost part of the code). With the preceding `2>&3`, it's essentially a move of fd 3 to 2, which could also be written as `2>&3-` (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Moving-File-Descriptors).

Comment: @philipp2100 see also [Practical use for moving file descriptors](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65000)

Answer (score 2):

second line can't work

```
({ sleep 2 & }; $MYPID=$!)
```

the `( ... )` fork a subshell, MYPID is set, then subshell exit and it's value is lost.

third line didn't work either

```
({ sleep 2 & }; echo $!) > $MYPID
```

you just echo $! to a file named 0 on local dir.

The only answer I can provide is via a temporary file (as var can't be push back)

```
 ( { sleep 100 & } ; echo $! > u ) > /dev/null &> /dev/null
 MYPID=$(<u)
```

you can replace `u` with any file.

Comment: Sounds good Archemar, I am using this process so far. However, I am not sure if there is a correct way to set temporary files? I am not sure if using `mktemp` or `> /tmp/file` Also what would be the best procedure after getting the PID? Should I remove the temporary file?